# Term for seeking to reaffirm your existing beliefs

Tags: single-word-requests

The word I'm looking for is similar to 'circlejerk', but rather than it being the participation of multiple people, I'm meaning one person seeking out studies/reading etc, for the sole purpose of reaffirming their existing beliefs or position on something, rather than to get to the truth of a matter.

The context this word would be used would be:

```
The article about messy desks being associated with genius, was a bit [word].
```

Similar to how you might say:

```
The atheists in the pub meet up, was a bit of a circlejerk.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self-affirming** is the word I went for.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias),

> **Confirmation Bias**
>
> The tendency of people to favor information that confirms their beliefs or hypotheses.

Or perhaps, [wishful thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishful_thinking) -

> **Wishful thinking**
>
> The formation of beliefs and making decisions according to what might be pleasing to imagine instead of by appealing to evidence, rationality, or reality.

**EDIT**

It is [self-serving](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-serving),

> **Self-serving** *adj.*
>
> Serving one's own interests often in disregard of the truth or the interests of others

Comment: Sorry, to be clear the word I'm looking for is an adjective.

Comment: No adjective can include "seeking", that's a verb.

Comment: Sure, I think strictly speaking it doesn't need to be an adjective, I've updated the question to give context.

Answer (score 0):

An analytical description could be 'mock openness', but I suppose this is not what you are after…

Answer (score 0):

**Self-congratulatory** more explicitly conveys an image of stroking one's own ego.